# Total gain of portfolio including sold stocks?

Tags: stocks, portfolio, tracking

I have a self-managed portfolio with a few stocks in it, which I keep at Scottrade and track with a program called StockMarketEye.  I've used a few other portfolio trackers as well, and they all seem to have the same problem - either that or I'm doing it wrong =o)

My problem is this:

Say I buy Stock A at $10 and ride it up to $100.
Then I sell Stock A and buy Stock B at $10 and ride it up to $100.
Then I sell Stock B and buy Stock C at $10.  Stock C falls to $9.

Since Stock A and B are no longer in my portfolio, they no longer show gains.  So now all I'm showing is that I own a bunch of Stock C at a 10% loss, even though my portfolio is way up overall.  This is discouraging.

I understand that it's important to know how your current stocks are doing, but I sort of feel like if I bought Netflix at $28 and then Tesla around $35 (I did both), the positions I've sold should still show up somewhere so I can see that "Oh, my current stock holdings are down 10%, but my overall portfolio is way up for the money that I've invested.

For some reason, I don't seem to be able to find software that will do that for me, even though it seems like it would be a no-brainer.

Does anyone know what I should be looking for in software, or how to get that sort of report?

Comment: I would talk to Scottrade support.  I would be surprised if they don't have a historical portfolio tracker as you describe.  I know that Schwab does.

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, some of these stocks were purchased before moving the portfolio to Scottrade.

Comment: I always assumed the "total value of holdings" was a good indicator of my current success :)

Comment: Why don't you just create your own spread sheet which you can have a starting capital, current balance, percentage gain/loss, open trade value, etc. and trace all your open and closed trades. You can also have other information on there such as stop loss levels (if you use them).

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own spreadsheet of Cash Flows and use the XIRR function in Excel:

```
Date     |    CF
------------------
1/1/2014     -1000   // Bought Netflix
2/25/2014     1500   // Sold Netflix for profit
4/1/2014     -1500   // Bought Ford
6/30/2014     1800   // Sold Ford for profit
6/30/2014    -1800   // Bought Google
6/30/2014     -300   // Bought Twitter
12/24/2014     250   // Sold Twitter for loss
12/25/2014    3000   // Sold Google for profit
------------------
XIRR:       103.2%
```

The formula is:

```
=XIRR(values, dates, [guess])
```